# Send text from sublimeText2 to R64.app on OS X

Tags: macos, r, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a simple plugin for Sublime Text 2 that will permit OS X users to send the selected text to R64.app for computation. So far I have the following:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os
class send2rCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self,blah):
        os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "R64" to activate'""")
        for sel in self.view.sel():
            sel_text = self.view.substr(sel)
            os.system('''osascript -e 'on run(args)' -e 'tell application "R64" to cmd (item 1 of args)' -e 'end run' -- "'''+sel_text+'''"''')
```

However, this seems to fail when the selected text contains the `$` character (a frequent occurrence in `R`). I also suspect that I've misunderstood something as I'm not sure why the `run` command fails (with an error in python) when I remove the `,blah` part of the `run` function definition.

Comment: Are you sure it's the fault of "$" not getting passed? There are several pitfalls to the use of "$" as an operator in R. Properly written application code in R will NOT have a lot of "$", since its use is recommended just for interactive use. Those of us R-users with Macs but without experience in `sublime` are going to need to see the "selected text".

Comment: Have you seen the RTools package? https://github.com/karthikram/Rtools

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be that one must replace `$` characters with `\$` before sending to osascript:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os
class send2rCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self,blah):
        os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "R64" to activate'""")
        for sel in self.view.sel():
            sel_text = self.view.substr(sel)
            sel_text = sel_text.replace('$','\$')
            os.system('''osascript -e 'on run(args)' -e 'tell application "R64" to cmd (item 1 of args)' -e 'end run' -- "'''+sel_text+'''"''')
```